# objective-c: help me understand views and modal transition

Tags: iphone, objective-c, storyboard, modal-dialog, segue

I'm lacking a serious understanding of how modal transitions work, so please do not leave the simplest answer out of this.

I have two views with their own view controllers set up in storyboard. A button on the main-menu leads to other-view. I set up this transition purely via ctrl-click and selecting the modal transition. I also have a button leading from the other-view back to the main-menu, set up similarly.

To further my understanding of these transitions I decided that I want the main menu to play a sound when it loads up, but only the first time i hit run, and not again when i go hit the button the other-view to go back to menu-view.

in my menu-view I have a private property BOOL

```
@interface MainMenuViewController ()
@property BOOL menuSoundPlayed;
@end
```

and my viewDidLoad...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if (!self.menuSoundPlayed){
        //sound setup code omitted for clarity
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(mySound);
        self.menuSoundPlayed = YES;
    }
}
```

can someone help me understand why the menu sound plays every time main-menu view loads? I do acknowledge that the menuSoundPlayed is never really initialized, but I dont know where I would even do that.

side-note: I love that apple gives us all these conveniences like story-board, but I almost wish it was easier to see all the code behind these things, so i could actually understand what was going on when i 'segue' between views.

Anyways, thank you!

Comment: Because a new instance of the VC is being created every time by the storyboard.  Setting properties doesn't matter jack when an instance is deallocated, and a new one is allocated

Comment: if the main menu is "loading", then viewDidLoad will be called. Ideally viewdidLoad should be called only once, unless an another viewController (of the same class) is being pushed on to the stack.

Answer (score 1):

I did a bit more researching and answered my own question.

In the situation I had before (described in my question) I had the code

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mainMenuSegue" sender:sender];
```

being executed, which as commenters described, starts a new instance of my main-menu.

What i wanted was to return to the main-menu instance already created.

To do this the following code is necessary (with your own completion block obviously):

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES
                         completion:^{
                             NSLog("view dismissed");
                         }];
```